# Return only distinct values from multiple SQL correlated sub-queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

This query partially completes. It returns 16 of 1,135 rows. The error message below indicates duplicates in the sub-queries.

I have tried inserting `DISTINCT` and `IN` syntax to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
SELECT a.AAAREFNUMVALUE AS "Pro Number",
   a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE AS "Table ID",
   a.AAAREFNUMTYPE AS "Number Type",
   a.AAAPROSUFFIX AS "Pro Suffix",
   d.AAADB2Date AS "Pickup Date",
   t.AAATOBILLINGTERMID as "Billing Terms",
   t.AAAOriginTerm as "Origin Terminal",
   t.AAADestTerm as "Destination Terminal",

(SELECT a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE 
        FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a2
        WHERE a2.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND
                a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 2
        ) AS "Shippers BL#",

        (SELECT a3.AAAREFNUMVALUE 
        FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a3
        WHERE a3.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND
                a3.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 3
        ) AS "PO #",

        (SELECT a4.AAAREFNUMVALUE 
        FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a4
        WHERE a4.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND
                a4.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 8
        ) AS "SHIPPERS #"

FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATODATES d ON a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE 
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATRANSPORTTABLE t ON d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = t.RECID
WHERE AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1 ;
```

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Subquery returned more than 1
>   value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= ,>, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: iám tempted to say you need to use a window function instead or a simple `SELECT TOP(1) ... ORDER BY ... ASC|DESC`.. but see [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: You have duplicates in the table used in the subquery.  You don't seem to expect, them, so you should investigate the contents of that table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error message doesn't indicate duplicates on the correlate subqueries, but multiple values. So it raises an error because the engine can't determine which of those values is the ones that should be returned.

You can add a TOP 1 on the subqueries to tell the engine that the first value of each subquery is the one to be returned.

```
SELECT a.AAAREFNUMVALUE AS "Pro Number",
   a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE AS "Table ID",
   a.AAAREFNUMTYPE AS "Number Type",
   a.AAAPROSUFFIX AS "Pro Suffix",
   d.AAADB2Date AS "Pickup Date",
   t.AAATOBILLINGTERMID as "Billing Terms",
   t.AAAOriginTerm as "Origin Terminal",
   t.AAADestTerm as "Destination Terminal",

(SELECT TOP 1 a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE 
        FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a2
        WHERE a2.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND
                a2.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 2
        ) AS "Shippers BL#",

        (SELECT TOP 1 a3.AAAREFNUMVALUE 
        FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a3
        WHERE a3.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND
                a3.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 3
        ) AS "PO #",

        (SELECT TOP 1 a4.AAAREFNUMVALUE 
        FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a4
        WHERE a4.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE  AND
                a4.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 8
        ) AS "SHIPPERS #"

FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS a 
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATODATES d ON a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE 
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATRANSPORTTABLE t ON d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = t.RECID
WHERE AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1 ;
```

But this is not recommended, because you shouldn't return a random value like that, you should check which subquery unexpectedly returns more than one value, and determine which is the correct of those multiple values, modifying that subquery so it returns that one (using an ORDER BY, for example).

Comment: No the results will be non deterministic  (**random**) when you use `TOP 1` without  atleast one column which is a deterministic column (meaning having a primary or unique key) in the `ORDER BY`.. Meaning every record which is matching the `WHERE` clause can be considerd the "first" record as the ANSI/ISO SQL standards have defined a resultset to be **orderless** without the use off `ORDER BY`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest transforming your subqueries to derived tables and then join to them.

```
SELECT     a.AAAREFNUMVALUE      AS "Pro Number"
         , a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE   AS "Table ID"
         , a.AAAREFNUMTYPE       AS "Number Type"
         , a.AAAPROSUFFIX        AS "Pro Suffix"
         , d.AAADB2Date          AS "Pickup Date"
         , t.AAATOBILLINGTERMID  AS "Billing Terms"
         , t.AAAOriginTerm       AS "Origin Terminal"
         , t.AAADestTerm         AS "Destination Terminal"
         , bl.AAAREFNUMVALUE     AS "Shippers BL#"
         , po.AAAREFNUMVALUE     AS "PO #"
         , sh.AAAREFNUMVALUE     AS "SHIPPERS #"
FROM       dbo.AAATOREFNUMS      AS a
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATODATES        AS d ON a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE
INNER JOIN dbo.AAATRANSPORTTABLE AS t ON d.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = t.RECID
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT a2.AAAREFNUMVALUE FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS AS a2) AS bl 
    ON bl.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE
   AND bl.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 2
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT a3.AAAREFNUMVALUE FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS AS a3) AS po 
    ON po.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE
   AND po.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 3
LEFT JOIN  (SELECT a4.AAAREFNUMVALUE FROM dbo.AAATOREFNUMS AS a4) AS sh 
    ON sh.AAATRANSPORTTABLE = a.AAATRANSPORTTABLE
   AND sh.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 8
WHERE      a.AAAREFNUMTYPE = 1;
```